# What will be the effect if I put a light source inside a swimming pool?

Tags: refraction

It can be a swimming pool or place with a certian level of water. The water is transparent and, inside of the pool, there is a small monochromatic light source. 
Now if I observe this from the outside, what will I see?

I know about refraction of light. So, when light will come to air from water and it will bend away from the normal. At some point the angle will be equal to the critical angle, the refracted ray will align with the surface. But how will I see a circle of light from outside? 
Also if I extend the refracted rays backward, will it give a virtual source of light? I mean, then there maybe lots of virtual light sources may see from the outside. 
Can anyone help?
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

If the pool is filled to the rim, you can see the light from everywhere around and over the pool. if the water level ist below the border you will see more than when the source is in the empty pool.
 but why not try it out with a flashlight in a closed plastic bag, the effect is the same in a small pool or container, and physics is about experiments!